# PHP web service call from phonegap is not working?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, web-services, cordova

I tried following code in phonegap for calling php webservice. I tested this code in eclipse web browser, it works well; Web service gets successful responce. But when I run project as android app. Web service fails, getting wrong message. I checked for internet permissions, thats ok. I dont get what happens there. Is there any mandatory access permission to call services?

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.7.2.min"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function clickJson(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                datatype:"JSON",
                //(Following url changed...) Working url. No problem with it...
                url: "http://www.domain.com/webservice/profile_details?panelist_id=1&panel_id=1",
                success: function(msg){
                    if (msg != ''){
                        alert("ok ");
                    }
                    else{
                        alert("No login details");
                    }
               },
               error : function(request, status, error)
               {
                   alert('error'+request.responseText);
               }
           });
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body style="padding:0; margin:0;">
         <button id="btnJson" onclick="clickJson();">JSON</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: got any error in console?

Comment: No it run successfully. But shows....

alert('error'+request.responseText);

Comment: replace error with alert('error'+ Json.stringify(request)); and tell me what exactly error getting in alert?

Comment: it's probably an issue with the whitelist plugin, google about it

Comment: It do not shows alert now.. I tried ur alert